# can't insert following_id into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my simple web app for following user, it has an error, please help me :) 
I can't insert following_id into database. I'm stuck with it

*This is my application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include WelcomeHelper
end
```

*WelcomeHelper

```
module WelcomeHelper
  def login(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

*relation_controller

```
class RelationController < ApplicationController
  def create
    follow = User.find(params[:relation][:following_id])
    current_user.following << follow
    redirect_to current_user
  end
```

*welcome_controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
 def create
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:session][:username])
      if user
      login user
      redirect_to user
    else
      render 'index'
    end
    end
 def sucess
   @users = User.all
   @relation = Relation.new
 end
end
```

*relation model

```
class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :follower_id, :following_id
  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :following, :class_name => "User"
end
```

*usermodel

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :pass, :username
# Who am I following?
      has_many :relations, :foreign_key => :follower_id
      has_many :following, :through => :relations
       # Who am I followed by?
      has_many :relations, :class_name => "Relation", :foreign_key => :following_id
      has_many :followers, :through => :relations


      validates :username, :pass, :presence => true
      validates :username, :pass, :length => { :minimum => 4 }
      validates :username, :uniqueness => true
```

*relations table

```
class CreateRelations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :relations do |t|
      t.references :follower
      t.references :following

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :relations, :follower_id
    add_index :relations, :following_id
  end
end
```

*routes

```
  get "welcome/sucess"
  get "welcome/error"
  root :to => "welcome#index"
  get '/users/:id', :to => 'welcome#sucess', :as => "user"
  match '/relations', to: 'relation#create', via: 'post'

  resources :users
  resources :posts
  resources :relations

  post   'login'   =>  'welcome#create'
```

*sucess view

```
Following
<ul>
  <% current_user.following.each do |u| %>
    <li><%= link_to u.username, u %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
Followed By
<ul>
  <% current_user.followers.each do |u| %>
    <li><%= link_to u.username, u %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
List Users<br />
<% if !@users.blank? %>
<% for @user in @users %>
<%= @user.username%><br />
    <%= form_for @relation do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :following_id, :value => @user.id %>
      <%= f.submit "Follow" %>
    <% end %>
<%end%>
<%else%>
<%end%>
```

when i click "follow" the following_id has been sent:(My current_user id = 9 )

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"NxOq/F5tOuElvhJNLOvkt/25enUN1wDI05I0fKp998Q=",
 "relation"=>{"following_id"=>"11"},
 "commit"=>"Follow"}
```

When i check Relation.all in rails console, the following_id has been insert, but when i check (as curent_user account)user.following - i see nothing, no following_id. I think something wrong in relation_controller at "current_user.following << follow".
I just can follow my current_user but it's ridiculous :)). So, please help me !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to sanitize parameters before you can put things into the database.

Read more http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Comment: i have created session for my current_user. when i click follow, the differnt id has been sent, not my current_user id. i think it isn't a matter

Comment: Google "Rails 4 strong parameters"

Comment: I dont know how to fix that :(